# Jest unexpected token - Typescript import

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I am getting the following error when I run `jest`. It looks like the cause is Typescript-related but I have some typescript handling in the package.json, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be handled.

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

...

Details:

    /Users/ryancocuzzo/ex/test/example/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-fs/FS.common.js:30
    var normalizeFilePath = (path: string) => (path.startsWith('file://') ? path.slice(7) : path);
                                 ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

    > 1 | import RNFS from "react-native-fs";
```

The library in question is [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

**package.json:**

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setupTests.js",
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "./node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Info:

```
react: 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.1
react-native-fs: 2.18.0
ts-jest: 27.1.3
jest: 26.6.3
babel-jest: 26.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization) ? Also related [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2081).

A workaround could be adding `react-native-fs` to the `transformIgnorePatterns`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<rootDir>` string token to include the path to your project's root directory to prevent it from accidentally ignoring all of your files in different environments that may have different root directories.

You also need to set the [test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#environment) for your react-native tests. so that it mimics the environment of a React Native app as it  doesn't load any DOM or browser APIs, which would greatly improves Jest's startup time.

```json
{
  //...

  "testEnvironment": "node",

  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
   // use <rootDir> absolute path here
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
  },

}
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately